# TensorFlow.js is Faster with Hardware Acceleration Turned Off (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tensorflow, hardware-acceleration

I'm learning to use the tensorflow.js library and I've written a super simple script.

```
    var NN = new NeuralNetwork(1);
    NN.addLayer(4);
    NN.addLayer(1);
    NN.Compile();
    console.log(NN.model);

    const test = [[0.25],
                  [0.31]];
    NN.Predict(test).print();

    const inps = [
        [0],
        [0.5],
        [1]
    ]

    const outps = [
        [1],
        [0.5],
        [0]
    ]    

    NN.Train(inps, outps, 1000).then(() => {
    NN.Predict(inps).print();
    });
```

The Neural Network class uses tensorflow

```
class NeuralNetwork
{
    constructor(a){
        this.model = tf.sequential();
        this.numInputs = a;
    }
    addLayer(nodes)
    {
        var layer;
        if(this.model.layers.length == 0){
            layer = tf.layers.dense({
                units: nodes,
                inputShape: this.numInputs,
                activation: 'sigmoid'
            });
        }
        else{
            layer = tf.layers.dense({
                units: nodes,
                activation: 'sigmoid'
            });
        }

        this.model.add(layer);
    }

    Compile()
    {
        this.model.compile({
            optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.1),
            loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError
        });
    }

    Predict(input)
    {
        return this.model.predict(tf.tensor2d(input));
    }

    async Train(inputs, outputs, num)
    {
        var response;
        const i = tf.tensor2d(inputs);
        const o = tf.tensor2d(outputs)
        const config = {
            epochs: 10,
            shuffle: true
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < num; index++) {
            response = await this.model.fit(i,o,config);
            console.log(response.history.loss[0]);
        }
      console.log("Training Complete.");
    }
}
```

The strange part is that when I ran this code I was surprised at how slow it too to complete, Taking around 3-4 minutes. I then went into my chrome settings to check that hardware acceleration was enabled and it was.

I then turned off hardware acceleration and ran the script again. To my surprise the script ran noticeably faster! Granted, it gave me some warnings about not being able to connect to webGL, but it was faster.

I've tried a few things (rebooting computer, checking chrome is up to date etc) and can't seem to figure out why I'm having this issue, I thought Tensorflow used the GPU? surely hardware acceleration should help?

Has anyone else had this issue? or have any suggestions of things I can try?